# ¿Por que no funciona mi codigo (fallo al recorrer un array de objetos)?

Tags: javascript, bucles, objeto

Estoy en haciendo unos ejercicios de Javascript y me deja el siguiente problema

```javascript
function pasarUsuarioAPremium(usuarios) {
  // "usuarios" es un array de objetos "usuario"
  // Cada objeto "usuario" tiene la propiedad "esPremium"
  // Define cada propiedad "esPremium" de cada objeto como "true"
  // Devuelve el array de usuarios
  // mi código:
  for (let i = 0; i < usuarios.lenght; i++) {
    usuarios[i].esPremium = true;
  }
  
  return usuarios;
}
```

y al testiarlo no funciona,me devuelve:

```
● pasarUsuarioAPremium(users) › should return the users array with each user's esPremium property set to true

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 5
    + Received  + 5

      Array [
        Object {
    -     "esPremium": true,
    +     "esPremium": false,
        },
        Object {
    -     "esPremium": true,
    +     "esPremium": false,
        },
        Object {
    -     "esPremium": true,
    +     "esPremium": false,
        },
        Object {
    -     "esPremium": true,
    +     "esPremium": false,
        },
        Object {
    -     "esPremium": true,
    +     "esPremium": false,
        },
      ]

      171 |       { esPremium: true },
      172 |     ];
    > 173 |     expect(pasarUsuarioAPremium(users)).toEqual(updatedUsers);
          |                                         ^
      174 |   });
      175 | });
      176 |
```

mi idea era crear un bucle que pase por cada objeto y reemplace la propiedad pero cuando la funcion devuelve el array sigue sin funciona, creo yo que es un problema con el codigo porque hice una prueba y tampoco funciona ¿es porque no uso `this`?.
tambien me gustaria entender mas sobre this
muchas gracias♥♥

Comment: Por favor agrega el código del test y todo lo relevante al problema

Comment: bro tu unico error es que escribiste LENGHT Y ES LENGTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No consigo ver la parte del código en la que está el error, pero una solución a tu problema es utilizar el método map, que recorrerá el array con los objetos creados y creará un array nuevo la propiedad de los objetos modificada, esto te simplificará las cosas. Dentro de este map puedes añadir la lógica para modificar la propiedad que deseas:

```js
const usuarios = [
  {
    nombre: 'Martin',
    esPremium: false
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Julian',
    esPremium: false
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Paco',
    esPremium: false
  }
]

const createPremiumUsers = users => {
  users.map( u => u.esPremium = true)
  console.log(users)
}

createPremiumUsers(usuarios)
```